# ASP.Net MVC: Webgrid with automatic ajax call related code injected and a issue occuring

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, webgrid

i am working with `webgrid ajaxUpdateContainerId` and as a result automatically scripts getting added in my page for ajax based sorting and paging. this is the script below which is added in my page dynamically.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        (function($) {
            $.fn.swhgLoad = function(url, containerId, callback) {
                url = url + (url.indexOf('?') == -1 ? '?' : '&') + '__swhg=' + new Date().getTime();

                $('<div/>').load(url + ' ' + containerId, function(data, status, xhr) {
                    $(containerId).replaceWith($(this).html());
                    if (typeof(callback) === 'function') {
                        callback.apply(this, arguments);
                    }
                });
                return this;
            }

            $(function() {
                $('table[data-swhgajax="true"],span[data-swhgajax="true"]').each(function() {
                    var self = $(this);
                    var containerId = '#' + self.data('swhgcontainer');
                    var callback = getFunction(self.data('swhgcallback'));

                    $(containerId).parent().delegate(containerId + ' a[data-swhglnk="true"]', 'click', function() {
                        $(containerId).swhgLoad($(this).attr('href'), containerId, callback);
                        return false;
                    });
                })
            });

            function getFunction(code, argNames) {
                argNames = argNames || [];
                var fn = window, parts = (code || "").split(".");
                while (fn && parts.length) {
                    fn = fn[parts.shift()];
                }
                if (typeof (fn) === "function") {
                    return fn;
                }
                argNames.push(code);
                return Function.constructor.apply(null, argNames);
            }
        })(jQuery);
        </script>
```

just tell me how to suspend this script when i click on links in header and pager.

```
$(document).on('click', '.webgrid-header a, .webgrid-footer a', function () {
    alert('Click on link');
});
```

i attached click event with all anchors in `webgrid header` and pager but not working because of the above dynamic script which is added in my page dynamically by webgrid because i choose the webgrid option `ajaxUpdateContainerId: "gridContent"`

i want when user click on links in webgrid header and footer then mu custom js function will run first and after that ajax call will start. so guide me how to achieve this. please guide.

thanks

Comment: It's strange because adding events to dynamically content is like you're doing it right now: `$(staticElement).on(event, dynamicElement, function());`
Is the `webgrid-header` dynamically generated aswell? Or just the a-tag?

Comment: the code i have given that is generate dynamically by webgrid. i have no control there.